# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface - using base64.b64encode

Tags: python, string, typeerror

I've taken a look at many other "*Questions that may already have your answer*", but didn't come across any that hit directly on the issue I'm running into.

Here's my **Python 2** snippet:

```
api_access_token = base64.b64encode('%s:' % api_access_token_setup)
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Any chance there's a quick fix for solving the error being prompted.

Comment: You need a *bytes* object, not `str`.

Comment: Pro tip when searching: add the function that caused the exception. Google had the duplicates in seconds when I searched for the exception and `64encode`.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you need to pass `bytes`, not `str` type to `b64encode`. Try encoding your string:

```
api_access_token = base64.b64encode(('%s:' % api_access_token_setup).encode())
```